# I need help identifying this NPN transistor

Tags: transistors, identification

I have a shorted NPN transistor in a marine LED motherboard.

From what I can see, it is a WY M1819 SMD package. I cannot find anything by this code. It’s a Chinese product and this code may just be a dummy. The package looks similar to the D1918 SMD package. The package dimensions are spot on. How can I be sure these two are identical?

[image: WY M1819]

---

Sorry about not posting more details, this is my first question here. This is a motherboard for a marine aquarium light fixture, Chihiros Nova 1 marine light. I am attaching a wider photo. Kindly take a look. Also, DPAK makes more sense, as this part of the board provides current to the blue leds on the light cluster. The package is about 6.45mm in width, and more or less 6mm in height.

[image]

Comment: You should post some more information about the circuit that device is part of. Maybe also a bigger photo to see the component in a wider context.

Comment: If it's shorted, how do you know it's a NPN?

Comment: Is it one of https://smd.yooneed.one/code5759.html

Comment: D1918 isn't any package I'm familiar with. This looks like either a bog-standard DPAK or D²PAK (it's hard to tell scale).

Comment: Hossain Mohd Faysal - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it wasn't the answer to your original question. It was additional information, so it has been added to your question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. Unless you are writing the *full and final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself and don't need further help) please don't use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead please edit the question to add new information & clarifications. (This is one way that Stack Exchange differs from forums. Please see the [tour] and [help] for more rules.) Thanks.

Comment: @Hearth - "1819" is almost certainly a date code.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast I'm referring to the text, where they say "looks similar to the D1918 SMD package".